# invalid syntax in python while trying to plot

Tags: python, syntax, plot

After my blunder with the infinity factorial sum XD I redid the code, but I keep getting syntax error :\

```
from scitools.std import *
from math import factorial, cos, e
from scipy import *
import numpy as np


def f1(t):
    return 0.5*(1 + sum( (a**(2*n)*cos(2*sqrt(1 + n)*t))/(e**a**2*factorial(n)) for n in range(0,100)))

a=4
t = linspace(0, 35, 1000)
y1 = f1(t)

plot(t, y1)

xlabel(r'$\tau$')
ylabel(r'P($\tau$)')
legend(r'P($\tau$)')
axis([0.0, 35.0, 0.0, 1.0])
grid(True)
show()
```

It says that there's an error in my program: invalid syntax and the a is red :\

What's wrong now? :(

EDIT:

I've added another ) at the end of the sum, but now I keep getting huge error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\faxstuff\3.godina\kvantna\vježbe\qm2\v8\plot.py", line 12, in <module>
    y1 = f1(t)
  File "D:\faxstuff\3.godina\kvantna\vježbe\qm2\v8\plot.py", line 8, in f1
    return 0.5*(1 + sum( (a**(2*n)*cos(2*sqrt(1 + n)*t))/(e**a**2*factorial(n)) for n in range(0,100)))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 1415, in sum
    res = _sum_(a)
  File "D:\faxstuff\3.godina\kvantna\vježbe\qm2\v8\plot.py", line 8, in <genexpr>
    return 0.5*(1 + sum( (a**(2*n)*cos(2*sqrt(1 + n)*t))/(e**a**2*factorial(n)) for n in range(0,100)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.float64'
```

Should I make so that the sum expression gives back an array from which I can plot or?

Comment: Your second error is a different question from your first error. Please make a new question.

Answer (score 4):

The parentheses in `return 0.5*(1 + sum(...` are not balanced.

As a matter of style, I would recommend avoiding `from <module> import *`-style imports. In your specific example you end up with a single-letter variable name (`e`) imported into the global namespace, which you then proceed to use. This could lead to confusion and, worse, hard-to-diagnose bugs.